# Multicol and Itemize

Tags: spacing, itemize, multicol

I am using the `multicol` package with `itemize`.  On the left of my two columns, each bullet point is 2 lines long, and on the right side, each bullet point is one line long.  Right now, my output is being displayed as:

[image]

However, I want the bullet points on the left and right columns to be aligned such that the first lines of each bullet point are aligned.  The code I am using right now is:

```
\begin{multicols}{2}
\textbf{Hello World}
\begin{itemize}
\item
    Hello: This, is, a, list, of, many, things, that, I, like
\item
    Goodbye: This, is, a, list, of, many, things, that, I, like
\end{itemize}
\columnbreak
\textbf{Goodbye World}
\begin{itemize}
\item
    Hello: One liner now
\item
    Goodbye: Still a one liner
\end{itemize}
\end{multicols}
```

How can obtain my desired output?

Comment: On the right column force the second line on each item: `Hello: One liner now\\ ~`.

Comment: Forcing the line worked perfectly. Great solution. Thanks @Sigur!

Comment: @Sigur Do you want to make that a solution?